# IF & Statement from excel to VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am a bit new to using VBA. I have a data table, that pulls data in from one of the programs I use, and is filtered through Microsoft Query. There is one column I can't sort, so I need to use an if and statement to remove unwanted data. I came up with this if statement, which highlights the rows I want to delete, but I don't know how to put it into VBA.

```
=IF(L5="Program",L6<>"lathe"),"2","")
```

Basically I want the VBA to look at Column L:L. If the cell=program, and the cell below does not equal lathe I want the row above to be deleted. If the cell doesn't equal program continue looking until the end of the data.

Comment: New logic, which I think will still use some of the old program, but it needed to be sorted using another column. I need the VBA to look at column E:E. If the cell in the row below is a duplicate of the cell above, then look at column L in that row to see if the cell says Program. If so the cell below should be Lathe. If not lathe delete the Program Row, If it is Lathe leave both rows. If the Cells in Column E are not duplicates, continue looking. EX. If E5=E6, If not continue looking. If yes Look at L5 to see if it say Program. If so look at L6 for Lathe. If not delete ROW5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBA, you'd use the IF ... And ... Then structure, thus:

```
If Range("L5")="Program" And Range("L6") <> "lathe" Then
    'Do something
End If
```

You'll probably want to replace the `Range(...)` statements with a range variable of some sort to store the cells you're really interested in, but that should give you an idea of the structure you're looking for.

EDITED TO ADD:

Loop through all of column L like this:

```
Dim rngCheck as Range
Dim rngCell as Range

Set rngCheck = Range("L1", "L" & Rows.Count - 1)

For each rngCell in rngCheck
    If rngCell.value = "Program" And rngCell.offset(1,0).value <> "lathe" then
        rngCell.offset(-1,0).EntireRow.Delete
    End if
Next rngCell
```

This:
Creates a range to look at (column L)
Loops through all cells in that column (the For each loop)
Runs our IF logic and
...deletes the entire row if the logic is met.

Comment: How would I make the VBA apply at the entire L:L column

Comment: You'd want to loop through the L column one cell at a time. I'll edit to reflect this structure.

Comment: Running into the Application-defined or object-defined error trying to run that.

Comment: My mistake - looping through all of column L is fine, but when you try to refer to the cell below the last cell, there isn't one, so it gives that error. Try the modification just posted.

Comment: There are some changes we could make for added efficiency, but they'd make the code harder to read, and I'm not sure the benefit would be worth it. Let me know if you'd like to explore that as well.

Comment: That worked, but my logic was wrong, and I didn't take into account some other fields. I will think about it some more to make sure the correct data is staying and ask again when I can clarify. Thanks again for the help

Comment: Any time. If you think it's been helpful, I'd appreciate an Accept :)

Comment: I added an updated logic if you may be able to help with that. I think it will still use what you came up with, we just needed something up front to help sort

Comment: Probably best to create a new question, and we'll look at it there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your idea behind it. you will just need to fix the format as you'd like.

```
If cells(5, "L") = "Program" AND cells(6, "L") <> "Lathe" Then
     cells (6, "M") = 2
Else
     cells (6, "M") = ""
EndIf
```

Answer (score 1):

The best is to loop on column L. Imagine your data is from row 3 to 150

```
for i = 3 to 150
   if lcase(range("L"&i).value) = "program" and lcase(range("L"&i+1).value) <> "lathe" then
       rows(i).entirerow.delete
   end if
next i
```